# NPM: How to build a project with git-based dependencies without having to call 'git' command?

Tags: node.js, docker, jenkins, npm

I have an NPM project that uses a git dependency

```
{
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://bitbucket.org/my-private-group"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "my-dependency": "bitbucket:group/lib#version",
  },
}
```

Now I want to *build this project in CI* using Docker with node installed.

**Problem:** `node install` tries to call `git` and fails because git is not there. But even if I install git it still requires authentication because it is a private repository.

At the moment I see the following solutions:

- I would have to install git in docker and add an SSH key to be able to download the source code.
- I may pack the related repository into the Docker image and use `npm link`. But this option still requires knowing dependencies set up in `package.json` which makes it complicated.
- Setup an own npm repository to post artifact and do not use git dependencies. This option is unfortunately not achievable in my case.

**Question:** What is the best way of handling git dependencies in CI? Are there any other options a part from the listed options. What is the best practice?

Comment: I don't know about bitbucket, but on github you can download a zip file with the source code. Your script could do that.

Comment: @K48 as I mentioned it is *a private repository*, you can't just download a zip without authentication. But even if you could how would you fetch git tag from it?

Comment: Github allows the same commit-ish pattern when downloading zips, like /archive/master.zip, /archive/v1.19.0.zip, /archive/af0d229.zip.

Comment: Honestly not clear what your intent is, how you want to use a repo if its private, there is no way

Answer (score 4):

Pulling from git without git installed is kinda hard. And installing git is easy. Just list is as a dependency for your project. `This project requires windows/linux/mac os, node js, git.`

You're allowing people to pull people from a private repo... that moment they have access to your source code...  so all use of having the repo private is lost anyway. Anyone who wants to duplicate your code can do easily the moment it's on their computer, even if it's obfuscated.

So, I would go back a step and ask you to start asking yourself why is the repo private? Is it code that is only distributed when an NDA is present? If so, you could consider working with ssh key files to log in.

Or, you could host your files on a privately hosted gogs server, where you whitelist IP's in the firewall/nginx router that can pull from the gogs repository on your server.

If you want anyone to be able to use your repository in the final distribution of your project, you're better off lifting the private setting of your repository. You might even get some free help fixing some bugs.

Answer (score 2):

I believe bitbucket has something called deployment keys which gives read only access to repositories. I am using deployment keys to build my private projects and its private dependencies.

The private key is stored in the CI server (Jenkins) and is injected into the appropriate project during its build process.

Another way is to use deployment keys with the private key stored in the project itself which can then be used during the build process.

*Update*

Assuming Jenkins Pipeline the following is an example of how to access ssh keys set in Jenkins using the [Credentials Binding Plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/)

```
stage('Sample') {
  agent {
    docker {
      image 'node:12'
    }
  }

  steps {
    withCredentials([
      sshUserPrivateKey(
        credentialsId: 'ssh-key-name-here',
        keyFileVariable: 'GIT_DEPLOY_KEY_FILE'
      )
    ]) {
      sh "cat $GIT_DEPLOY_KEY_FILE"
    }
  }
}
```

*Update Sept 16th 2019*

I recently came across the [Build Enhancements made in Docker 18.09](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#using-ssh-to-access-private-data-in-builds).
I have not yet to explore this but I think it can be used to solve the credential problem.

Comment: I am doing it the same way (through an ssh key on the Jenkins machine). But the I need to run a build inside a docker container which is started by the Jenkins machine.

Comment: Check out the credential binding plugin https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/ I am using this to pass the credentials into the container. I have updated my answer